# Which one is correct? as referred by /as referred to by

Tags: prepositions

I am contacting you as referred by Salim/
I am contacting you as referred to by Salim.
Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Hello Mansoor. Neither is correct. If you mean Salim "told" you, or "instructed" you to speak to (X) then you might say, "I have been referred to you by Salim". If Salim simply "suggested" you speak to X, or "recommended" you to, then "Salim suggested/recommended I get in touch with you." "As referred" is not useful here.

Comment: Why is that comment not an answer?